# Visual bug when rendering Microsoft Bahnschrift to PDF from InDesign

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-indesign, typography

I'm using Microsoft's new variable font [Bahnschrift](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/08/23/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16273-pc/) in one of my InDesign projects. InDesign doesn't support the variable aspects of the font, but can display the regular weight without issue. When I export the document to a PDF file though, I noticed the capital `A` has weird gaps inside the letterform

[image: gaps inside the capital A letterform]

Looks like the letter was designed as two distinct shapes and simply placed over one another, with a wrong Illustrator pathfinder action.

Only the InDesign PDF output is broken. InDesign displays the font properly in the edit window. Also, the macOS Textedit app (which supports variable fonts to a degree) displays and renders to a correct PDF, which lets me think this is an InDesign issue.

Is there something I can do, short of editing the font files? Maybe there is a setting in the InDesign export options I'm missing?

I'm using version 1.00 of Bahnschrift, InDesign CC 2018 (also tested on 2017).